# PHP search form security improvements and other recommendations

Tags: php, mysql

I have following code for search functionality using MySQL database;

My questions are;

1) How can I highlight the searched word in the search results (as I
    have shown in screenshot).

2) `art_content` field of my `articles` table contains whole article
    content. How can I show only first few sentences of the articles in
    the search results?

3) I want to protect this from SQL injection and other attacks. I
    have used `strip_tags`, `mysqli_real_escape_string`, `trim`. Are
    these functions are enough? Are there any suggestions?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEPAQ.jpg)

Here is my code;

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="search" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            Search for: <input type="text" name="searchtext"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Search"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    /* PHP simple search engine */
    /*
        CREATE TABLE articles(
            art_id INT(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            art_title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            art_date DATE NOT NULL,
            art_content TEXT NOT NULL,
            art_url VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
        );

        INSERT INTO articles
        VALUES(1, 'Pirith Chanting in Galle', '2016-01-07', 'More than 200 students and Dhamma school teachers attented the ceremony.', 'galle_pirith.html'),
        (2, 'Foods Distribution in Polonnaruwa', '2016-01-21', 'Vitims of flood received relief from foods distributed. President also participated', 'polo_foods.html'),
        (3, 'Donations for Dhamma Schools', '2016-02-11', 'Financial support was given to Dhamma schools in remote areas in Galle district', 'dhamma_donation.html');
    */
if( isset($_POST['ok']) ){
    $input = $_POST['searchtext'];

    if( $input=="" ){
        echo "<h1>Please enter a search term!</h1>";
        exit;
    }

    $con = @mysqli_connect( "localhost:3306", "root", "P@ssw0rd", "DogSport" ) or die ("Couldn't connect to server");

    //filtering input for XSS and SQL injection
    $input = strip_tags( $input );
    $input = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $input );
    $input = trim( $input );

    $query = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE art_title LIKE '%$input%' OR art_content LIKE '%$input%'";

    $result = mysqli_query ( $con, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute SELECT query: ". mysqli_error($con));

    $nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo "<h3>". $nrows. " results found!</h3>";
    echo "<h4>You searched for: ". $input. "</h4>";

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
            extract($row);

            echo "<br><b> $art_title </b>";
            echo " - ";
            echo "<b> $art_date </b><br>";
            echo "$art_content<br>";
            echo "<a href=$art_url>$art_url</a><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) To highlight search terms use str_replace() function.

```
echo str_replace($input, '<em>'.$input.'</em>', $variable_name);
```

You can use tags such as , ,  to highlight text with css added

2) Use substr() function to extract only certain portion of the text

```
if (strlen($art_content) > [desired length of text])
{
    echo substr($art_content, 0, [desired length of text]) . '...';
}
else
{
    echo $art_content;
}
```

3) To protect from SQL injection use PDO prepared statement
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059